# Add custom action to rename file to msi installer with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows-installer, python-multiprocessing, cx-freeze

there is a bug in cx_Freeze with the multiprocessing package where it copies the "pool.pyc" as "Pool.pyc" which results in a runtime error: "no module named multiprocessing.pool".

To mitigate this, I wanted to include a VBScript with my installer to rename that file post-installation to keep my build process automatic.

I tried this:

```py
msi_custom_action = [
    (
        'rename_pool',              # identifier
        22,                         # custom action type, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/custom-action-type-22
        'installer_helper.vb',      # source
        None,                       # target
        None,                       # extendedtype
    )
]

msi_sequence = [
    (
        'rename_pool',              # name of action
        None,                       # condition
        6601,                       # sequence (6600< after files are copied)
    )
]

msi_data = {
    "Shortcut": msi_shortcut_table,
    "CustomAction": msi_custom_action,
    "InstallExecuteSequence": msi_sequence,
}

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'optimize': 1,
        'includes': ['atexit'],
        'include_files': [('./qt/', 'qt/'), './TableManipulationsDialogOperations.json', './single.rc', './matplotlibrc', './installer_helper.vb'],
        'packages': packages,
        'excludes': ['scipy.spatial.cKDTree', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'], # cKDTree excluded bc of a bug, ckdtree still available
    },
    'bdist_msi': { # first three options remove need of admin rights for installer
        'initial_target_dir': r'[LocalAppDataFolder]\spleng',
        'add_to_path': False,
        'all_users': False,
        'data': msi_data,
        'target_name': 'Spleng_Installer',
    }
}

# execute build
setup(
    name="SplENG",
    options=options,
    version='0.1.1',
    description='SplitExplorerNextGeneration',
    executables=executables
)
```

But while creating the installer, I receive this error:

```
creating dist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 146, in <module>
    executables=executables
  File "C:\Users\-\Documents\git_repos\spleng\.venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 340, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\-\Documents\git_repos\spleng\.venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\windist.py", line 420, in run
    self.add_config(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\-\Documents\git_repos\spleng\.venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\windist.py", line 74, in add_config
    msilib.add_data(self.db, tableName, data)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\msilib\__init__.py", line 104, in add_data
    assert len(value) == count, value
AssertionError: ('rename_pool', 22, 'installer_helper.vb', None, None)
```

Can someone tell me how to properly add the script, I can't really make heads or tails with the docs.
I'm using cx_freeze version 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole problem can be avoided by adding 'multiprocessing.Pool' to the excludes in the setup.py.

https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/353